# Best way to program multiple alarms

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating an application that allows users to set multiple alarms.

The two ways I can think of doing is:

1. Store alarms as rows in a table and have a cron job check them every
   minute. However, this means that the alarms will only be checked
   every minute while some users may want it to be checked at a finer
   resolution.
2. Create a new timer object for each new alarm that will call itself
   with a setTimeout function. But if the app crashes then the alarms
   are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try to [node-scheduer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule).
Very much similar to the cronjob. But the application must be kept on running.

It executes an event on a given interval. Make sure the job is executed after the desired interval every time and Put the alarm functionality there.